# OMP Optimal way to copy matrix

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix, parallel-processing, openmp

I need to optimize this C code using OpenMP. What is the optimal solution?

```
#define accessMat( arr, exp1, exp2 )    arr[ (int)(exp1) * columns + (int)(exp2) ]

for( i=0; i<iter && i<rows; i++ ) 
        for( j=0; j<columns; j++ )
            accessMat( flow_copy, i, j ) = accessMat( flow, i, j );
```

Comment: How big is your matrix? Copying data is often bounded by the speed of the memory hierarchy (caches & RAM) and not by the computing core themselves. For small matrices , the implicit communications between cores are much more costly than just moving data sequentially. If you want to move data efficiently, you can use the optimized `memcpy` function.

Answer (score 0):

You try simply by parallelizing the copy

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j)
for( i=0; i<iter && i<rows; i++ ) 
    for( j=0; j<columns; j++ )
        accessMat( flow_copy, i, j ) = accessMat( flow, i, j );
```

you can also test with collapse (i.e.,  `#pragma omp parallel for(2)`), but I think the parallel task does not have enough grain to overcome the overhead of the collapse clause.

You can also play around with OpenMP simd, namely:

```
#pragma omp for simd collapse(2) 
for( i=0; i<iter && i<rows; i++ ) 
    for( j=0; j<columns; j++ )
        accessMat( flow_copy, i, j ) = accessMat( flow, i, j );
```

and on so. Test and check if you gain any benefit.